# scrape ASIN from amazon URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, amazon-ec2

Assuming I have an Amazon product URL like so

```
http://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Wireless-Reading-Display-Generation/dp/B0015T963C/ref=amb_link_86123711_2?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_r=0AY9N5GXRYHCADJP5P0V&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=500528151&pf_rd_i=507846
```

How could I scrape just the [ASIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Standard_Identification_Number) using javascript?
Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Amazon's detail pages can have several forms, so to be thorough you should check for them all. These are all equivalent:

[http://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Wireless-Reading-Display-Generation/dp/B0015T963C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0015T963C)
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0015T963C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0015T963C)
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0015T963C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0015T963C)
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/glance/B0015T963C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0015T963C)

They always look like either this or this:

```
http://www.amazon.com/<SEO STRING>/dp/<VIEW>/ASIN
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/<VIEW>/ASIN
```

This should do it:

```
var url = "http://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Wireless-Reading-Display-Generation/dp/B0015T963C";
var regex = RegExp("http://www.amazon.com/([\\w-]+/)?(dp|gp/product)/(\\w+/)?(\\w{10})");
m = url.match(regex);
if (m) { 
    alert("ASIN=" + m[4]);
}
```

Comment: One more possible form: amazon.com/exec/obidos/asin/B0015T963C. Just to be completely comprehensive the regex could be extended with `dp|gp/product|exec/obidos/asin`.

Comment: Building on this, and adding support for international characters, odd ports, https, non-US domains, and query/tracking parameters (and I'm using Java) it would be:
Pattern asinPattern = Pattern
   .compile("^(http[s]?://)?([\\w.-]+)(:[0-9]+)?/([\\w-%]+/)?(dp|gp/product|exec/obidos/asin)/(\\w+/)?(\\w{10})(.*)?$");

Comment: Even after @JasonThrasher's update, it still didn't work for the url: https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00W36QH4C?me=&amp;ref=olp_product_details#immersive-view_1438138820146  
Gumbo's solution seemed to be working for all my urls

Comment: For some reason, for me, this regex fails to extract this URL:
http://www.amazon.com/Rising-Strong-Bren%C3%89-Brown-ebook/dp/B00P5557G2/ref=zg_bs_154830011_4/190-0944759-0347263

Comment: This regex won't work for that link - https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B003IKGX6O/ref=zg_bs_2975358011_13?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=QSFTFSQ2AAQDFF4R4V68&th=1

Comment: How's the regex considering also `https://smile.amazon.com` as well as other TLDs like `http://www.amazon.co.uk` and without SLD `https://amazon.fr`?

Answer (score 25):

Since the ASIN is always a sequence of 10 letters and/or numbers immediately after a slash, try this:

```
url.match("/([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})(?:[/?]|$)")
```

The additional `(?:[/?]|$)` after the ASIN is to ensure that only a full path segment is taken.

Comment: There are multiple cases where it doesn't work: http://www.amazon.com/BEAUTBRIDE-Womens-Beaded-Wedding-Fingerless/dp/B010Q0Y92I ... http://www.amazon.com/LOSLANDIFEN-Elegant-Stiletto-Wedding-6041-04Silk42/dp/B019PMTJH8. I can confirm that because I was using a similar approach :)

Comment: @OscarMederos Works for me in both cases.

Comment: Doesn't work with https://www.amazon.com/Blitz-Gem-Jewelry-Cleaner-Concentrate/dp/B000F1SCU4?psc=1&SubscriptionId=AKIAINYZIU4KZ7G6NVLQ&tag=amzntelegramn-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B000F1SCU4

Comment: Note that the ASIN for books is the ISBN and ISBNs after 2007 have 13 chars (instead of the older 10 chars length).

Comment: I edited your matching a bit so that it is this `.*/([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})(?:[/?]|$).*`
This also can get the ASIN from @ecdeveloper 's url

Answer (score 10):

Actually, the top answer doesn't work if it's something like amazon.com/BlackBerry... (since BlackBerry is also 10 characters).

One workaround (assuming the ASIN is always capitalized, as it always is when taken from Amazon) is (in Ruby):

```
        url.match("/([A-Z0-9]{10})")
```

I've found it to work on thousands of URLs.

Comment: and it doesn't work on many other. See my comment on Gumbo's answer

Comment: @OscarMederos It should work on both the examples you gave, because the ASIN is still 10 uppercase/numerical chars after a "/".  So it wouldn't match the beginning of the URL, but would still match the end.  Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @osman he is right - your example won't work on some links. Try this one out - http://www.amazon.com/BEAUTBRIDE-Womens-Beaded-Wedding-Fingerless/dp/B010Q0Y92I. BEAUTBRIDE is 10 characters, so it will match that instead of B010Q0Y92I.

Answer (score 6):

None of the above work in all cases. I have tried following urls to match with the examples above:

```text
http://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Wireless-Reading-Display-Generation/dp/B0015T963C
http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0015T963C
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0015T963C
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/glance/B0015T963C

https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00LGAQ7NW/ref=s9u_simh_gw_i1?ie=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00LGAQ7NW&pd_rd_r=5GP2JGPPBAXXP8935Q61&pd_rd_w=gzhaa&pd_rd_wg=HBg7f&pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=GA7GB6X6K6WMJC6WQ9RB&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=c210947d-c955-4398-98aa-d1dc27e614f1&pf_rd_i=desktop

https://www.amazon.de/Sawyer-Wasserfilter-Wasseraufbereitung-Outdoor-Filter/dp/B00FA2RLX2/ref=pd_sim_200_3?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=NMR7SMXJAKC4B3MH0HTN

https://www.amazon.de/Notverpflegung-Kg-Marine-wasserdicht-verpackt/dp/B01DFJTYSQ/ref=pd_sim_200_5?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=7QM8MPC16XYBAZMJNMA4

https://www.amazon.de/dp/B01N32MQOA?psc=1
```

This is the best I could come up with: `(?:[/dp/]|$)([A-Z0-9]{10})`
Which will also select the prepending / in all cases. This can then be removed later on.

You can test it on: http://regexr.com/3gk2s

Comment: I'm using it in Javascript: why does it return an Array and why the ASIN starts with `/`?

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly for me, I tried all the links on this page and some other links:

```
function ExtractASIN(url){
    var ASINreg = new RegExp(/(?:\/)([A-Z0-9]{10})(?:$|\/|\?)/);
    var  cMatch = url.match(ASINreg);
    if(cMatch == null){
        return null;
    }
    return cMatch[1];
}
ExtractASIN('http://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Wireless-Reading-Display-Generation/dp/B0015T963C/ref=amb_link_86123711_2?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_r=0AY9N5GXRYHCADJP5P0V&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=500528151&pf_rd_i=507846');
```

- I assumed that the ASIN is a 10-length with capital letters and
  numbers
- I assumed that after the ASIN must be: end of the link, question mark
  or slash
- I assumed that before the ASIN must be a slash

Answer (score 2):

Try using this regex:

```
(?:[/dp/]|$)([A-Z0-9]{10})
```

Check out the demo:
https://regexr.com/3gk2s

Answer (score 1):

@Gumbo: Your code works great!

//JS Test: Test it into firebug.

```
url = window.location.href;
url.match("/([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})(?:[/?]|$)");
```

I add a php function that makes the same thing.

```
function amazon_get_asin_code($url) {
    global $debug;

    $result = "";

    $pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})(?:[/?]|$)";
    $pattern = escapeshellarg($pattern);

    preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);

    if($debug) {
        var_dump($matches);
    }

    if($matches && isset($matches[1])) {
        $result = $matches[1];
    } 

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my universal amazon ASIN regexp:

```
~(?:\b)((?=[0-9a-z]*\d)[0-9a-z]{10})(?:\b)~i
```

Comment: Hey! It's really nice and crisp and short. Could you please explain the working of this pattern step-by-step?
That would be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a simplistic approach, but I have yet to find an error in it using any of the URL's provided in this thread that people say is an issue.

Simply, I take the URL, split it on the "/" to get the discrete parts.  Then loop through the contents of the array and bounce them off of the regex.  In my case the variable i represents an object that has a property called RawURL to contain the raw url that I am working with and a property called VendorSKU that I am populating.

```
try
            {
                string[] urlParts = i.RawURL.Split('/');
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[A-Z0-9]{10}");

                foreach (string part in urlParts)
                {
                    Match m = regex.Match(part);
                    if (m.Success)
                    {
                        i.VendorSKU = m.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
```

So far, this has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of change to the regex of the first answer and it works on all the urls I have tested.

```js
var url = "http://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Wireless-Reading-Display-Generation/dp/B0015T963C";
m = url.match("/([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})(?:[/?]|$)");;
print(m);
if (m) { 
    print("ASIN=" + m[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by many of the answers here, I found that

`(?:[/])([A-Z0-9]{10})(?:[\/|\?|\&|\s|$])`

```
let url="https://www.amazon.com/Why-We-Sleep-Science-Dreams-ebook/dp/B06Y649387/ref=pd_sim_351_4/131-0417603-5732106?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B06Y649387&pd_rd_r=5ebbfdd5-a2f6-4ee3-ad13-5036b5e20827&pd_rd_w=LBo2H&pd_rd_wg=OBomS&pf_rd_p=3c412f72-0ba4-4e48-ac1a-8867997981bd&pf_rd_r=TN0WDV3AC7ED4Y7EKNVP&psc=1&refRID=TN0WDV3AC7ED4Y7EKNVP"
url.match("(?:[/])([A-Z0-9]{10})(?:[\/|\?|\&|\s])")

>> Array [ "/B06Y649387/", "B06Y649387" ]
```

works really well for extracting asin from anywhere in the url. You can try it out here. https://regexr.com/56jm7

edit: Added end-of-string as one of the stopping checks. This is needed when the regex is used in python

Comment: Why do you have alternators "|" *inside your character class brackets* []???  Also within [], only "/" needs to be escaped, and $ is a literal "$" sign.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work (not tested)

```
var match = /\/dp\/(.*?)\/ref=amb_link/.exec(amazon_url);
var asin = match ? match[1] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia article on ASIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Standard_Identification_Number) (which I've linkified in your question) gives the various forms of Amazon URLs. You can fairly easily create a regular expression (or series of them) to fetch this data using the [`match()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can [scrape ASIN codes](https://truemiller.com/scrape-amazon-asin/) from the `data-asin` attribute in the search results using XPath.

For example `$x('//@data-asin').map(function(v,i){return v.nodeValue})` can be ran in Chrome's console.

Answer (score 0):

Used both methods in a single function:

```
const extractASIN = (url: string) => {
  var regex = RegExp('(?:[/])([A-Z0-9]{10})(?:[/|?|&|s])');
  const m = url.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    return m[1];
  }
  return url.split('/ref')[0].split('/dp/')[1];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// function to find the nth instance of character in string
function nthIndex(str, pat, n) {
  var L = str.length,
    i = -1;
  while (n-- && i++ < L) {
    i = str.indexOf(pat, i);
    if (i < 0) break;
  }
  return i;
}
// this function takes a string and split string list as parameters and slices off entirely after that character is found
function splitSliceFunc(splitStr, splitStrList) {
  for (i = 0; i < splitStrList.length; i++) {
    splitStr = splitStr.split(splitStrList[i])[0];
  }
  return splitStr;
}
try {
  const amzUrl = 'https://www.amazon.com/Encyclopedia-Country-Living-50th-Anniversary/dp/1632172895/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=survival+encyclopedia&pd_rd_r=8e62738c-ae2b-46c0-b477-db5cf23a6b0a&pd_rd_w=0Eazc&pd_rd_wg=E51TF&pf_rd_p=54cea6b7-0efb-45a3-b68b-8c1ccfbfa553&pf_rd_r=EE9X3J3QBPCDQAVQJ9FQ&qid=1651929404&sr=8-1';
  const sliceUptoAsinList = ["/dp/", "/gp/product/"]; // list for slice occurrences before asin
  const sliceAfterAsinList = ["/", "?"]; // list for slice occurrences after the asin
  let sliceUptoAsin; // variable to store index of slice occurrence before asin
  let shortenedUrl;
  // if else statements for all the possible slice occurrences before asin
  if (amzUrl.includes(sliceUptoAsinList[0])) {
    sliceUptoAsin = nthIndex(amzUrl, "/dp/", 1);
    shortenedUrl = amzUrl.slice(sliceUptoAsin + 4); // + 4 to remove /dp/ also
    console.log(sliceUptoAsin, shortenedUrl);
  } else if (amzUrl.includes(sliceUptoAsinList[1])) {
    sliceUptoAsin = nthIndex(amzUrl, "/gp/product/", 1);
    shortenedUrl = amzUrl.slice(sliceUptoAsin + 12); // + 12 to remove /gp/product/ also
    console.log(sliceUptoAsin, shortenedUrl);
  } else {
    throw "url format not supported";
  }
  // removes everything after the asin following 'sliceAfterAsinList'
  shortenedUrl = splitSliceFunc(shortenedUrl, sliceAfterAsinList);
  console.log(shortenedUrl);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

I opted for a non regex approach because they become harder to maintain. IF you are treating the urls as simple strings, split and slice can also do the job.

The above code assumes that the ASIN is followed by "/dp/" or "/gp/product/" (*but is not limited to these occurrences only because 'sliceUptoAsinList' array can have as many as slice occurrences before ASIN as many you want, followed by an added else-if condition).

The code will work irrespective of whether there are 10 or more characters in ASIN because it will only look for the first occurrence of any character found in the 'sliceAfterAsinList' array in the url and will remove everything next to that character (including the character also).

I have built a tool for this purpose [github repo](https://github.com/kghosein/small-amz-tool).

Answer (score -2):

If the ASIN is always in that position in the URL:

```
var asin= decodeURIComponent(url.split('/')[5]);
```

though there's probably little chance of an ASIN getting %-escaped.

Comment: It isn't always in that position. Amazon URLs have many forms, like http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0015T963C

Comment: This assumes the ASIN will always be in the exact position. That is not a safe assumption.